# Multi-site deployment using git and a CI

Tags: php, git, github, continuous-integration, web-deployment

Currently, I'm using github to host my code repo and then pushing updates to my sites via copy and pasting files onto the server via FTP. However, the host I'm using allows ssh access there must be an easier way to do this.

What I'm looking to do is the following:

- Set up a Jenkins (a CI) that checks all my code before deploying it live.
- Be able to deploy from a single repo to multiple sites.. BUT each site has one or two unique files in them (such as a view with a Google Analytics code in them).

From my Google-ing so far I can either deploy via GitHub's webhooks that they offer or doing it through Capistrano.

So, my question is ***what is the best way to go about setting everything up?***

*NOTE: I'm still a programming n00b so mind anything that I haven't taken into consideration while asking the question*

Comment: *Best* is subjective and greatly depends on circumstance.

Comment: Well I meant best in terms of the scenario I described in the above question

Answer (score 0):

Within your repository, you could have two root level folders. One for the site and one to contain site specific files. For **each site**, create a Jenkins build configuration to perform the following:

1. Checkout code of your git repository
2. Perform any build actions
3. Copy site files across to production
4. Copy site specific files to production

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local repository that has a `clean script` which will change the settings in those specific files as you want when checking out a version.

This is covered in the **git attributes** chapter in the **keyword expansion** section of the Pro Git book:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

Answer (score 0):

You might find it simpler to just use [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) for uploading your changes.  This script stores the name of the last uploaded commit on the server in a special file, and when you re-upload, it sends only the files which have been changed since the state which has been uploaded last.  Things like file/directory renames/deletions are handled properly as well.  In our setup, we found this script easier to use than rolling some higher-profile solutions.